# Where can I find Firefox's about:blank file to customize it?

Tags: firefox

I'm interested in creating a custom about:blank file for myself, but I can't seem to find it. 
This one [site](http://www.oyyas.com/articles/customize-firefox-s-about-blank-page) that did have information on what I wanted was very outdated. Is there a modern equivalent for that tutorial?

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, you're almost definitely better off just changing the new tab page. You can change it in `about:config`. The preference option is `browser.newtab.url`. Simply create any HTML file and point this towards that file.

If you still *really* want to modify the `about:blank` file, the tutorial you found should still be valid. You'll just have to create the `chrome` folder and `userContent.css` file manually - they are not automatically created.